# How to get logs of the container made with `buildah from`?

Tags: containers, buildah

I create an image using:

```
buildah bud --layers --format docker -t ${imageFullName()} -f ${componentName}/DockerfileTests ${buildArgsStr} ${componentName}
```

And then create a container:

```
buildah from ${imageFullName()}
```

The question is - how to get logs of the build container?

Comment: Is buildah running on docker?

Comment: The containers made with buildah are compatible with docker commands but in my situation i can't use `docker logs` command

Comment: `docker logs` applies to the running container, not building it. For building in docker, consider buildkit. Otherwise, I don't think the docker tag belongs here.